# How to use ECDH webCrypto deriveBits and node ECDH to have same results?

Tags: node.js, webcrypto-api

I trying establish a shared secret between browser and nodejs with ECDH.

I trying to use `deriveKey` or `deriveBits` of `crypto.subtle` from Web Cryptography API at client and the `createECDH` from `node:crypto` at Node side, and find this problematic:
the `deriveKey` just accepts key type (like `AES-CBC`) and length like `256`. I suspect it uses something similar to `hkdf` of Node crypto module, but with what kind of hash, salt, and iterations I should apply to hkdf at node side to match browser output?